# Background-size gets stuck on values over 100%?

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure out what's going on here. Saw a really cool example of how to do background transitions on http://www.gradient-animator.com/

However, when I went to plug them into my test site, the background remains solid and doesn't do the transition until you disable the background-size property in the developer console, and then re-enable it.

I just for the life of me, can't figure out what's wrong...

```css
@-webkit-keyframes gbpr {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes gbpr {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes gbpr { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0ae6ae, #2d80f3, #bd2df3, #f32d57);
  background-size: 800% 800%;

  -webkit-animation: gbpr 30s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: gbpr 30s ease infinite;
  animation: gbpr 30s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any problem in your snippet, what is your question ?

Comment: run the snippet, open the developer console inspecting it, and uncheck background-size then re-check it and watch the result.

Comment: I am seeing the animation work as intended.

Comment: yeah somehow I fixed it but I'm not quite sure what I did... and that's really frustrating

Comment: Probably all those odd `!important`s without anything to override, and the 51% values.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking if you have it set to !important on the gradient, the animation doesn't have the ability to take over

Answer (score 0):

If you include !important on a liner gradient, the animation cannot move it. Simple as that.